# "Please enter a complete address" error when adding/updating subscriber's address

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm using MailChimp's API v3.0 and having problems when trying to update the subscriber's postal address.

The data I'm sending is:

```
[method] => patch
[path] => lists/123456789/members/membershash
[url] => https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/123456789/members/membershash
[body] => {"merge_fields":{"FNAME":"firstname","LNAME":"lastname","TITLE":"Mr","BDAY":"10\/11","TSTATUS":"approved","ADDRESS":{"addr1":"10811 International Drive","city":"Rancho Cordova","state":"CA","zipcode":"95670"}}}
[timeout] => 10
[headers] => PATCH /3.0/lists/123456789/members/membershash HTTP/1.0
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
400: Your merge fields were invalid. Please enter a complete address.
```

I've tried sending it as a string (fields separated by double spaces as described in the import file schema), i.e.

```
10811 International Drive  Rancho Cordova  CA  95670
```

but I got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here. Using the same format as for API v2.0.  Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I ended up having multiple address fields for the country, city, etc. I still don't know what the correct format is. :/

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you're still looking... I'm using the [Drewm](https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api) wrapper and updating mailing address by using the following:

```
$subscriber_hash = $MailChimp->subscriberHash($email);
$result = $MailChimp->patch("lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash", [
            'merge_fields' => [
            'FNAME'     =>  $firstname, 
            'LNAME'     =>  $lastname, 
            'ADDRESS'   => array
                (
                    'addr1'   => $addline1,
                    'addr2'   => $addline2,
                    'city'    => $city,
                    'state'   => $state,
                    'zip'     => $zip,
                    'country' => $country
                )
            ],
            'interests'    => [$interest_id => true],
        ]);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The "enter a complete address" error will happen if you do not send a value for `country`.

Both `addr2` and `country` are optional, but MailChimp secretly requires you to send an empty string for `country` whereas you can leave out `addr2` entirely.

MailChimp support told me this:

> You are right that the only required parameters of the Address object
>   is addr1, city, state, and zip. That being said, for parity with
>   performance of the application, the "country" parameter would need to
>   be present and be given an empty string value. The empty string will
>   resolve to the default_country. Which if not changed is the US.
>
> I understand that this is not completely consistent with the
>   documentation. I will pass along this feedback to our team that
>   oversees our schema as this can create confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have a foreign address? The country would be filled in, but many of them do not have values for the state and zip/postal code.